# Oil pressure level

Tags: oil-pressure, seat-ibiza

Yesterday the oil pressure light beeped on my car suddenly as i was driving and my engine seized up, causing me to have to leave it by the side of the road. An hour later, me being unexperienced and forgetting to check the manual, returned to my car and tried to start it again. It started fine and I was able to drive it home with the engine sounding and feeling normal, and there were no warning lights on the dash except for an emission control yellow light that came on.

I googled what happens when you drive a car with low oil pressure and got very scared, and this morning I checked the engine oil level and it was slightly over the maximum level. I tried starting the car and it started fine and made no noises with no low oil pressure lights coming on. I drive a used Seat ibiza 2006 1.4 with 100,000 miles that I have had for only a month or so. Should i be driving the car at all? What could be the cause of this

Thanks

Comment: Good advice in the answer, it could be a loose connection or a short or the switch failing - get it to someone who can read the codes and wait to see what the results are.

Comment: how much is "slightly over the maximum limit"? before starting your car again remove the excess oil first, having either too low or more than maximum oil both can cause severe damage to the engine

Answer (score 3):

Your engine didn't seize, if it had it would never have turned over again and it would have required a complete overhaul or replacement. It quit on you, and that's not good, but it's better than having to replace the engine.

It's not possible to say what's happened to your car without more details like ODB codes. It could be anything from an ignition problem to sensors to fuel pressure, or a combination of things. It probably **isn't** the oil. As for is it safe to drive I'd say probably not, it already quit on your once and left you on the side of the road, and it will probably do it again - potentially in a dangerous situation. Get thee to a mechanic.